# Function composition

Tags: c#, functional-programming

Below a `Compose` function. If `f` and `g` are unary functions which return values, then `Compose(f,g)` returns a function which when called on `x` performs the equivalent to `f(g(x))`.

```
static Func<X, Z> Compose<Z, Y, X>(Func<Y, Z> f,Func<X, Y> g) 
{ return x => f(g(x)); }
```

Here's a couple of simple `Func` values which can be composed:

```
Func<int, bool> is_zero = x => { return x == 0; };

Func<int, int> mod_by_2 = x => { return x % 2; };
```

E.g. this works:

```
Console.WriteLine(Compose(is_zero, mod_by_2)(4));
```

However, if I instead have these equivalent static methods:

```
static bool IsZero(int n) { return n == 0; }

static int ModBy2(int n) { return n % 2; }
```

the same example doesn't work with those. I.e. this produces a compile time error:

```
Console.WriteLine(Compose(IsZero, ModBy2)(4));
```

Explicitly passing types to `Compose` fixes the issue:

```
Console.WriteLine(Compose<bool, int, int>(IsZero, ModBy2)(4));
```

Is there anyway to write `Compose` such that it works on the static methods without the explicit types?

Is this a good approach to take to implementing `Compose`? Can anyone make improvements to this?

Comment: C#'s rigidity in its treatment of function/delegate types is one thing that's always frustrated me when compared to duck-typed languages like JavaScript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is not the use of `static` methods but the use of method groups.  When you use a function name as an expression without invoking it then it's a method group and must go through method group conversion.  You would have the exact same problem with instance methods.

The problem you're running into is that C# can't do return type inference on method groups.  Using `Compose(IsZero, ModBy2))` requires the return type to be inferred for both `IsZero` and `ModBy2` and hence this operation fails.

This is a known limitation in the inference capabilities of the C# compiler.  Eric Lippert wrote an extensive blog article on this particular subject which covers this problem in detail

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx

Comment: I note that the article is slightly out of date. In this particular case it is correct; you cannot do inference on the method groups because we have a chicken-and-egg problem; we cannot determine what the delegate types are until we know what method is chosen from the method group, and we cannot do overload resolution on a method group until we know the delegate *formal parameter* types. If, by contrast, the delegate *return types* were being inferred but the *formal parameter types* were all somehow known then return type inference would work on method groups.

Comment: _When you use a function name as an expression without invoking it then it's a method group and must go through method group conversion._
OK. So the name `IsZero` refers to a method group. But in this case, there is clearly only one method in the group, and thus no ambiguity about the return type. Obviously the compiler team decided against taking advantage of these cases (single method groups). Would it have been unsound to do otherwise? (Let me know if I should open a separate question for this... :-))

Comment: Of course, another unambiguous case would be method groups where all methods in the group have the same return type.

Comment: Also, I haven't yet studied Eric's post (I tend to have to study, not just read, his posts... :-)). Sorry if the answer to my question in the comments is clarified there.

Comment: OK, Eric does mention this point in the article: _Sure, in this case there is only one method in the method group and it is not generic, so we could just pick it. But we ought to solve the general problem here._

Comment: Alright, I've made it through Eric's article. I'm still groking it, but as far as I can tell, there's no good justification for the compiler not handling the single-method in a group case.

Comment: @dharmatech: of course there is a good justification. It would be *bizarre* if we had one overload resolution algorithm for the case where there was only one method in the method group and a *completely different* algorithm if there were two. That would mean, for instance, that *adding a new unambiguous overload to your program could cause it to fail to compile*.  More generally, making a languages that requires that its compiler reasons about *all possible logical inferences* is not our goal; making a language that has *clear and consistent rules* is a goal.

Comment: @EricLippert After going through your article a couple more times, the issues are starting to sink in. I appreciate your response. :-)

Comment: @EricLippert Today I ran across [this behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256355/passing-f-function-to-ienumerable-where-vs-ienumerable-all?noredirect=1#comment35588660_23256355) in F#. It reminded me of this comment you made. :-) Sort of the inverted case.

Comment: the link is broken