# Passing F# function to IEnumerable.Where vs IEnumerable.All

Tags: .net, linq, f#

Given the following:

```
open System.Linq

let even n = n % 2 = 0

let seqA = seq { 0..2..10 }
```

this is a valid expression:

```
seqA.Where(even)
```

but this is not:

```
seqA.All(even)
```

Why is passing `even` to [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allowed but not to [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Linq.Enumerable.All%60%601%29;k%28DevLang-fsharp%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29&rd=true)?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: My guess is you've discovered a bug. I would send this to fsbugs@microsoft.com.

Comment: This seems to be another case of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933366/f-func-type-inference-difference-between-seq-and-pseq-todictionary). As a workaround, `seqA.All(System.Func<_,_>(even))` should work, or `seqA.All(fun x -> even x)`.

Comment: FYI, I've just opened an [idea on uservoice for this](http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5823074-stronger-type-directed-conversion-from-functions-t).

Comment: @ChristophRüegg voted! :-)

Comment: @Daniel fsbugs requested that I open an issue on their codeplex site. [Here it is](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/46).

Comment: `even |> seqA.All` does work (on mono). Just to make things more interesting.

Comment: why people don't like the `Seq.all even seqA` approach?

Comment: remembers me about my similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960985/whats-wrong-with-s-countchar-isletter which however raises a different fsc error.

Comment: I tried using even |> seqA.All and that works. But seq.All(even) is indeed not allowed.

Comment: @ChristophRüegg consider making your comment a top-level answer. I'd at least consider that to be a valid 'solution.'

Comment: You can verify that [kvb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933366/f-func-type-inference-difference-between-seq-and-pseq-todictionary/12937079#12937079) (linked by @ChristophRüegg) applies: Introduce a dummy overload `type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<'T> with member __.All _ = false`. Now `seqA.All(even)` compiles.

Answer (score 1):

While there may be a bug there, I think the better approach would be to use the Seq higher order functions when dealing with `IEnumerable<T>` in F# rather than Linq

```
let even n = n % 2 = 0
let seqA = seq { 0..2..10 }

seqA |> Seq.filter even
//val it : seq<int> = seq [0; 2; 4; 6; ...]

seqA |> Seq.forall even
//val it : bool = true
```